# Set chart axis label for individual groups with an expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm on VS2012 SSRS and trying to do a report prepared for each AgentID. The agent needs to see his bar highlighted and IDs for other agents should be hidden.

We agreed I can go with **plan A** putting  or **planB** completely hiding IDs other than the selected one from horizontal label.

I've illustrated this in the picture with ID 22222.

I managed to highlight the bar with an expression on the `fill` property of the series. But I'm not sure how to modify the axis label individually. I think that the property for axis label refers to the label for every group. I can hide all of them, but can't manipulate them individually.

[image]

Comment: I added my sample rdl.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/rx9gind2dt3p17w/Agent_Chart.rdl?dl=0

Answer (score 2):

In the category group properties you can dynamically assign the axis label for the entry. This is on a value-by-value basis and only effects the labels, not the grouping. So if you have multiple labels that end up the same they won't end up grouped together.

[image: category group menu]

[image: category group properties]

So in your case the expression for the label would probably be something like

```
=IIF(Fields!AGENT_ID.Value=Parameters!AGENT_ID.Value,Fields!AGENT_ID.Value," ")
```

Do note: I've used a space(" ") and not just an empty string(""). Using an empty string SSRS will fill the empty categories with numbers. A space will blank out the category name.

Comment: Thanks, Mike for your solution and fixes for my axe/axis. It works now but partially, in a place of empty "" Agent_ID  labels I'm getting some kind of grid:  like  0, 2, 3, 2222,8,10,12.   I played with it and see it works OK if I put some literal into false section. Just curious what this could be, some kind of default grid ?  Thanks again.M

Comment: I confirmed that if you don't put anything "" VS puts grid of total number of Categories, and it's impossible to change this default, unless you HIDE labels.  I'm trying now play with <Show Data Labels> property, I need somehow stress/highlight given bar. Even I change color it's blends with other as I have 100+ categories..  M

Comment: I've update the answer. If you use a space(" ") instead of an empty string("") it will actually blank out the names.

Comment: Do you need to show all 100+ categories? That is always going to make for an extremely cluttered chart. Can you show the average of the other categories instead of all of them?